# Run .Net Framework 4.8 dll in .Net 6

Tags: migration, .net-6.0, shim

I am migrating my application from .Net 4.8 to Net 6.0. During the migration, I found some libraries that I could not find alternatives in .Net 6.
Is it possible to run .Net 4.8 dll in .Net 6?
If it is possible, how can I do it?
Do you know any examples?

Comment: If u can find alternatives in .Netstandard you are good to go , if not I don't think that u can move to .net6 since those are yours blockers for transition.

Comment: As a side note. I'm using this (https://www.nuget.org/packages/CyotekImageBox/) winforms control (which is net framework-only for version which I use) in my app. And this control still working after migration on net6. I'm getting a number of compiler warnings about this, but actually this is working somehow. But I still would not recommend suach an approach for production.

Comment: @Serg Yeah, agree with you, it is not for production, but for the intermediate stage it works, when we need to split our migration work.